# round image in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to make an image round. I always used maskCircle but this time it does not work. I wrote the code in UICollectionViewCell's awakeFromNib and I can not use viewDidLayoutSubviews since I'm dequeueing the cell in cellForItemAt function. So this is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var storeLogo: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    storeLogo.maskCircle()
    storeLogo.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

and the imageView looks like this: 
[imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MSZE.png)

edit: 
it seemed to work fine, but i have the problem again.
this is the code in awakeFromNib now:

```
    super.awakeFromNib()
    storeLogo.clipsToBounds = true
    storeLogo.layer.cornerRadius = storeLogo.frame.width / 2

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 55, height: 55))
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradient.colors = [Color.storeName?.cgColor, Color.idTint?.cgColor]

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    let radius: CGFloat = 27
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -2.5, y: -14, width: 2.0 * radius, height: 2.0 * radius), cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - radius, y: self.frame.midY - radius)
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    self.storeLogo.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

and the image is not round as you can see in this image: [imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRr9n.png)
i

i don't know why the image is not a circle now. any idea?!

Comment: and wow. out of nowhere, this works fine:         super.awakeFromNib()
        storeLogo.maskCircle()
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        ... and i have no idea why it is working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do round clip on `UIImageView` set `cornerRadius` of `UIImageView`.

```
storeLogo.layer.cornerRadius = storeLogo.frame.width / 2
storeLogo.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: aha, it did work! but why maskCircle is not working? this is maskCircle's function:
    func maskCircle() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.layer.borderColor = Color.gray?.cgColor
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

Comment: where you write `maskCircle()` ?

Comment: yes i wrote it in extension, what makes the problem then?